# MySQL: Select values based on current month and day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called **history** that includes a column called **month**: January, February, March, etc. and a column called **day_num** containing day numbers from 1 to 31.

I need to be able to select a month and a day from the two corresponding columns, based on the current month and day.

I know it's a rather embarrasingly basic question, but - how do I do that?

```
SELECT month, day_num FROM history WHERE ??????? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Would appreciate a bit of advice from a knowledgeable person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    History
WHERE   DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%M') = `month` AND
        DAY(CURDATE()) = `day_num`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eff59/3)

OR

```
SELECT  *
FROM    History
WHERE   MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) = `month` AND
        DAY(CURDATE()) = `day_num`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eff59/2)

Other Sources

- [MONTHNAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)
- [DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)

Comment: LOL, this is the reverse of what I asked about, but it pointed me in the proper direction, thank you very much Kuya!